# function call from viewmodel to view controller class

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to call one function in ViewController class which was written in view model class.But unfortunately that function is not getting called.I am not getting that where I did mistake.If anyone helps me ,Would be great. Thankyou!

```
//ViewController Class
import UIKit

class getDetailsViewController: UIViewController {

    var getviewmodel: getDetaisViewModel?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func getDetailsAction(_ sender: Any) {

       getviewmodel?.getdetailscall()
    }
}

//ViewModel Class

import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON


class getDetaisViewModel{
 var url: URL!

    func getdetailscall(){

        let headers:HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization":"application/json"]
        print(headers)

        url = URL(string: Constants.apiForGetDetails)
        print(url)
        let vc = getDetailsViewController.init(nibName: "getDetailsViewController", bundle: nil)
        getWebService.requestService(url: url, method: .post, headers: headers, showLoaderFlag: true, viewController: vc, completion: { response in

            guard response["code"].int != 503 else {
                print("No internet connection")
                return
            }

            guard response != .null else {
                return
            }

        })
    }

}
```

Comment: Becuase you haven't initialized the getviewmodel object

Comment: did you inject the instance of viewModel to your view controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Becuase you haven't initialized the `getviewmodel` object

Change

```
var getviewmodel: getDetaisViewModel?
```

to

```
var getviewmodel = getDetaisViewModel()
```

Or initialize `getviewmodel` object in `viewDidLoad` method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()    
    self.getviewmodel = getDetaisViewModel()
}
```

Change your class name to `GetDetaisViewModel`